# itextsharp Modifying Table Header Row on Page break

Tags: itext, page-break

I am using itextsharp pdfptables in columns. I have a table that is very long and goes across multiple pages. The header, "XYZ", repeats as it should but I want the header to be "XYZ - Continued" on subsequent pages. I have tried looking for an event in the table but no luck!

I am working in VB.net but samples in C# work too.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend taking a look at [`PdfPTableEvent`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTableEvent.html).

There's also a [document level page event](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEvent.html), though it's not as helpful in this case.

I think you'll need a partially blank header, and then have to fill in the variable parts during your `PdfPTableEvent` callbacks.

Yes, this documents the Java version of iText.  However, all the methods are identical, or very nearly so.  Your IDE should help you iron out any differences.